# Adaptation of the fast Poisson solver (MKL) to the zero based indexing in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, intel-mkl

I have this problem where I am trying to solve Poisson equation (which is only one of the three coupled equations in an iterative process) by using the Intel MKL set of subroutines (Fast Poisson Solver Subroutines). 
Now, it is important that I mention that my entire code (several thousand lines) is written assuming zero based indexing in the following way:

```
arbitrary_array(0:N),arbitrary_matrix(0:N,0:M)
```

where N and M are the gridpoints in x and y direction, respectively.
Since I am aware that MKL Poisson solver has one-based indexing, I wrote the following subroutine to do the necessary conversion:

```
    SUBROUTINE POISSON_SOLVER_MKL(N,M,Phi,Div,Ja,Lx,Ly,dx,dy)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    !
    INTEGER,INTENT(IN)::N,M               !Zero-based index count
    REAL(DP),INTENT(IN)::Div(0:N,0:M)     !This is right-hand side of PE
    REAL(DP),INTENT(IN)::Ja,Lx,Ly,dx,dy   !BC,X and Y size of the system,unit cell size

    REAL(DP),INTENT(OUT)::Phi(0:N,0:M)    !This is left-hand side of PE
    INTEGER::NX,NY                        !One-based index count
    INTEGER::stat,ipar(128)               !MKL parameters
    REAL(DP)::ax,bx,ay,by,q
    REAL(DP),ALLOCATABLE::dpar(:),f_POISSON(:,:),bd_ax(:),bd_bx(:),bd_ay(:),bd_by(:)
    TYPE(DFTI_DESCRIPTOR),POINTER::xhandle
    CHARACTER(4)::BCtype

        NX=N+1    !This is where indices are shifted
        NY=M+1
        ALLOCATE(dpar(13*NX/2+7),f_POISSON(NX+1,NY+1),bd_ax(NY+1),bd_bx(NY+1),bd_ay(NX+1),bd_by(NX+1))
        !Allocation of the arrays and matrices required for MKL solver
        q=0.d0     !Set for Poisson equation
        ax=0.d0    !First coordinate in x direction
        bx=Lx      !Last coordiante in x direction
        ay=0.d0
        by=Ly
        BCtype='NNNN'     !Set the Boundary Conditions to be all Neumann
        bd_ax=0.d0
        bd_bx=0.d0
        bd_ay=-Ja
        bd_by=Ja
        ipar=0
        CALL D_INIT_HELMHOLTZ_2D(ax,bx,ay,by,NX,NY,BCtype,q,ipar,dpar,stat)
        PRINT*,'STAT=',STAT
        f_POISSON(1:NX+1,1:NY+1)=Div(0:N,0:M)    !Transferring the variables from zero-based indexing to one-based indexing
        CALL D_COMMIT_HELMHOLTZ_2D(f_POISSON,bd_ax,bd_bx,bd_ay,bd_by,xhandle,ipar,dpar,stat)
        PRINT*,'STAT=',STAT
        CALL D_HELMHOLTZ_2D(f_POISSON,bd_ax,bd_bx,bd_ay,bd_by,xhandle,ipar,dpar,stat)
        PRINT*,'STAT=',STAT
        Phi(0:N,0:M)=f_POISSON(1:NX+1,1:NY+1)    !Returning the variables from one-based indexing to zero-based indexing
        CALL FREE_HELMHOLTZ_2D(xhandle,ipar,stat)
        PRINT*,'STAT=',STAT
        DEALLOCATE(dpar,f_POISSON,bd_ax,bd_bx,bd_ay,bd_by)

    END SUBROUTINE POISSON_SOLVER_MKL
```

Unfortunately, this entire chunk of code is compiled without any error, but the results I obtain have not much sense.
This leads me to a conclusion that I may have made an error in index transformation and allocation, but I simply do not see where this error is.

Has anyone encountered similar type of problem?

Comment: Turn bounds checking on for debugging purposes.

Comment: f_POISSON(1:NX+1,1:NY+1)=Div(0:N,0:M) with NX = N+1 and NY = M+1, then size inconsistent?

Comment: So, I am not quite sure if I understood the comment @HighPerformanceMark gave, but this is what I now did: I wrote another subroutine that works on the assumed shape array arguments. But even in that case I still need size of the gridspace so I can define BC internally.

Comment: This page may be useful: http://sep.stanford.edu/sep/claudio/Research/Prst_ExpRefl/ShtPSPI/intel/mkl/10.0.3.020/examples/pdepoissonf/source/s_Poisson_2D_f.f90

Comment: Thanks @roygvib, I am looking at this for the entire day, and I tried to mimic the form in the example provided there, but I still get the same results, instead of convergence the solution now oscillates.

EDIT>
Also, do you have any idea why in the example provided on that page after the definition of nx and ny all of the loops go from 1 to nx,y+1?

Comment: @Itzaak I guess this is because the arrays are declared as A( nx+1, ny+1) rather than B( 0:nx, 0:ny ) in the example (so A(1,1) corresponds to B(0,0)). Another point is that we can change the lower bounds of arrays when passed to subroutines (I hope there is some good explanation about this somewhere...)

Answer (score 0):

Following [this page](http://sep.stanford.edu/sep/claudio/Research/Prst_ExpRefl/ShtPSPI/intel/mkl/10.0.3.020/examples/pdepoissonf/source/s_Poisson_2D_f.f90), `NX` and `NY` seem to be the number of mesh intervals (not grid points), so it seems okay to receive `Div` as either `Div( 0:N, 0:M )` or `Div( N+1, M+1 )` in the dummy arguments (the same for `Phi`) and set `Nx = N` and `Ny = M`. If we use the latter, the modified code may look like this (but not tested yet, so please try with actual data):

```
SUBROUTINE POISSON_SOLVER_MKL(N,M,Phi,Div,Ja,Lx,Ly,dx,dy)  !! the same input should be used
IMPLICIT NONE
!
INTEGER,INTENT(IN)::N,M                ! Number of mesh intervals (not grid points)
REAL(DP),INTENT(IN)::Div( N+1, M+1 )   !This is right-hand side of PE
REAL(DP),INTENT(IN)::Ja,Lx,Ly,dx,dy    !BC,X and Y size of the system,unit cell size

REAL(DP),INTENT(OUT)::Phi( N+1, M+1 )  !This is left-hand side of PE
INTEGER::stat,ipar(128), Nx, Ny        !MKL parameters

REAL(DP)::ax,bx,ay,by,q
REAL(DP),ALLOCATABLE::dpar(:),bd_ax(:),bd_bx(:),bd_ay(:),bd_by(:)
TYPE(DFTI_DESCRIPTOR),POINTER::xhandle
CHARACTER(4)::BCtype

    Nx = N
    Ny = M

    !! The grid points now read as x(i) = ax + (i-1) * (bx - ax)/nx
    !! for i = 1,2,...,nx+1 (similar for y)

    ALLOCATE( dpar(13*Nx/2+7), bd_ax(Ny+1), bd_bx(Ny+1), bd_ay(Nx+1), bd_by(Nx+1) )

    q=0.d0     !Set for Poisson equation
    ax=0.d0    ! lower bound of x
    bx=Lx      ! upper bound of x
    ay=0.d0    ! lower bound of y
    by=Ly      ! upper bound of y
    BCtype='NNNN'     !Set the Boundary Conditions to be all Neumann
    bd_ax=0.d0
    bd_bx=0.d0
    bd_ay=-Ja
    bd_by=Ja
    ipar=0

    CALL D_INIT_HELMHOLTZ_2D ( ax, bx, ay, by, Nx, Ny, BCtype,q,ipar,dpar,stat )
    PRINT*,'STAT=',STAT

    CALL D_COMMIT_HELMHOLTZ_2D ( Div, bd_ax, bd_bx, bd_ay, bd_by, xhandle,ipar,dpar,stat )
    PRINT*,'STAT=',STAT

    CALL D_HELMHOLTZ_2D ( Div, bd_ax, bd_bx, bd_ay, bd_by, xhandle,ipar,dpar,stat )
    PRINT*,'STAT=',STAT

    Phi(:,:) = Div(:,:)  !! [Q] Div overwritten with the solution? Plz check the manual...

    CALL FREE_HELMHOLTZ_2D(xhandle,ipar,stat)
    PRINT*,'STAT=',STAT

END SUBROUTINE POISSON_SOLVER_MKL
```

Please note that we do not need to modify the calling subroutine (the arrays used there may be 0-based like `Div(0:N, 0:M)`), and that we do not need to do copy-in/copy-out of `Div` using `f_poisson`.

---

We can also write the same routine with 0-based indices (as in the question). In this case, the grid points become `x(i) = ax + i * (bx - ax)/nx` for i = 0,1,...,nx (similar for y), and it is probably better to declare boundary arrays also to be 0-based, for example

```
SUBROUTINE POISSON_SOLVER_MKL(N,M,Phi,Div,Ja,Lx,Ly,dx,dy)
IMPLICIT NONE
!
INTEGER,INTENT(IN)::N,M                ! Number of mesh intervals
REAL(DP),INTENT(IN) ::Div( 0:N, 0:M )   !This is right-hand side of PE
REAL(DP),INTENT(OUT)::Phi( 0:N, 0:M )   !This is left-hand side of PE
...
Nx = N
Ny = M

ALLOCATE( dpar(13*Nx/2+7), bd_ax(0:Ny), bd_bx(0:Ny), bd_ay(0:Nx), bd_by(0:Nx) )
...
! other parts are the same
```

Comment: @Itzaak Because I have never used Poisson solver in MKL and wrote the above modified code very roughly, there may be still mistakes, so plz be careful! Edit> Sorry, I declared Nx and Ny as real variables, but these should be integers of course (<-- i.e. typos)